# C++ Add this pointer to a container by calling it in base class constructor

Tags: c++

```
class Base
{
public:
Base (int a, int b);
private:
int a,b;
};

class Derived1
{
public:
Derived1():base(1,2){}
};
```

similarly Derived2, Derived 3 which doesnt contain any data members on its own

Now i need to contain these derived objects in a singleton, so i was thinking to call this in base constructor like

```
Base::Base(int a, int b)
{
CBaseMgr::GetInstance()->AddtoVector(this);
}
```

so now if i construct

Derived d1, d2, d3 etc. will the Singleton's container contain all derived objects?

My doubt is can i do this adding of objects to container in base ctor or should i do in derived ctor.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the derived class call this base class constructor, yes, you should be fine.

Just beware of the *copy constructor* which, if not overloaded, will **not** add `this` to your global vector.

I suppose you want as well remove the instances that were destroyed, from the global vector ?

If so, don't forget to declare `Base::~Base` to be `virtual`, so that he gets called by derived classes.

Comment: Removing the this instances in Base dtor, In this case i think the container has to be a map, since in vector how do i remove that "particular derived object". So if in a map, if i use say" description" data member as the key, will it still be valid in base dtor. I mean, when does the data members get deallocated in dtor, at the end of dtor's {}?

Comment: +1 for mentioning that all constructors need to be overloaded.

Comment: @vivekeviv: you don't need a map, you can certainly call `std::find` with a value (in case an instance of `Base*`). However, you should consider using a `set` or `unordered_set` if you plan on having a good number of elements at a given point in time (say ~1000).

Comment: @vivekeviv: As Matthieu M. said, using a `map` here is not needed. Remember that you just have a `vector` of pointers (a "number" if you want). Each instance will have it's own and unique "number" that will **never** change during its life-time. So yes, you can just remove it from the vector as you would do it with an integer value. Just beware that once an instance has been destroyed, another **might** reuse its address (aka. "number") again. So be sure to *always* remove them on destruction.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in Base's constructor should be fine, as long as you're not dereferencing `this` before the whole construction is done.

Answer (score 0):

> My doubt is can i do this adding of
>   objects to container in base ctor or
>   should i do in derived ctor.?

You can safely do it in the base constructor but you have to take care of the following:

- explicitely declare copy constructor semantics (if you want objects to be copy-constructible, fine; if not, declare the base copy constructor as private, and do not implement it, or make Base inherit privately from `boost::noncopiable`).
- store Base references as pointers (I guess you already know this).
- declare base's destructors virtual (and have them remove the instance from the manager)
- make sure the removal process doesn't throw any exceptions ( throwing exceptions in destruction may lead to transforming the Earth into a singularity or other undefined behaviour :) ).

Comment: You have typo: it should be `boost::noncopyable`

Comment: pl check my comment on ereOn reply. Thanks for the help

Comment: The order of destruction is the following: if you have `class derived: public base { int i; };`, first `derived::~derived` gets executed, then `i` becomes unavailable (if it has a non-pod type it's destructor gets called), then base::~base gets called, then all the destructors of the members of base.

In your case, if the description is a member of base, it is safe to remove the base* from a map in the destructor, and to have the base* stored by a description held in base.